# How can I fix "1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64" in Xcode c++?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have just added this code:

```
class a
{ 
public:
    static int b;
};

int a::b;
```

and it works everywhere extend of Xcode. I tried to change "No commond blocks" from "Yes" to "No" in targets->Build settings->Apple Clang - Code Generation, but it didn't help. I use SFML in my project, so i clicked on checkbox "For install builds only".

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Is `int a::b;` in a header file ?  It should be in 1 and only 1 .cpp file.

Comment: Don't put `int a::b;` in a header file.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, it is in my header file, but I am trying to write a library and write all classes in header file. Is it correct? Or I should write all classes in main?  But how then make classes, which people can use and not know about internal organization of classes?

Comment: ***Or I should write all classes in main?*** No.

Comment: Put `int a::b;` in a `cpp` file. Also you may want to initialize `b` at the same time. `int a::b{};`